# Conditional Sum in using R to create a new data.frame

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, conditional-statements

I wanna to create a new data frame with Group (A,B,C,D,E) and Total consumption (Totalcons) basing on the following data.frame.

```
  id group consumption
1   1     A  100
2   2     A  210
3   3     B  300
4   4     B  214
5   5     C  254
6   6     C  124
7   7     D  145
8   8     D  652
9   9     E  245
10 10     E  150
```

How to calculate sum of Consumption depending on each group? Actually, I have to work with larger data.frame with thousands of group so this is only for example. Could someone tell me how to do it in R program and applying in case of much larger data.frame? 
Thank you for your time!
Best

Comment: From your description, it is only  sum per group.  Is there any additional condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do `sum` per group you can also use `ave` (not the most efficient solution but an alternative!):

```
set.seed(32)
df = data.frame(group=rep(letters, 10000), consumption=rnorm(260000))

summary = data.frame(
    letters = letters,
    sum     = with(df, ave(consumption, group, FUN=sum))[1:26]
)
#   letters         sum
#1        a    3.485019
#2        b   77.740427
#3        c  -22.349616
#4        d   94.100463
#5        e  -98.697508
# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming your data frame is named `dat`, then you can try  this

```
with(dat, tapply(consumption, group, sum))
```

Answer (score 3):

For very big datasets,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(consumption=sum(consumption)), by=group]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(consumption= sum(consumption))
```